# Does the system use NSOperationQueue mainQueue for its own calls?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsoperation

I want to add a lot of `NSBlockOperations` to the `mainQueue`, and potentially call `[mainQueue cancelAllOperations];` My question is, does the class method `mainQueue` only have operations that I could have added to it, or does the system add any of its own operations to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the documentation does not say one way or the other and I would be quite surprised if anyone from Apple can tell you in absolute terms. I would guess it does not, but have a suggestion for you on how you can determine this for yourself.

In a current app, send "- (void)setSuspended:YES;" to the mainQueue, then add a dispatch_after block to the dispatch_main_queue, and log the operationCount of the mainQueue. In fact you could suspend it in the appDelegate on launch, and provide a button that prints the count out so you could really exercise your app. I'd be quite surprised if any of the UIKit frameworks uses it.

I just tried it an iOS app of mine and never found any:

```
// in one place
[((NSOperationQueue *)[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]) setSuspended:YES];
// Eons later
NSLog(@"[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] %d", ((NSOperationQueue *)[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]).operationCount);
```

The value was 0;